# Linux Mint on VirtualBox has no internet connection

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, linux-mint

Physical machine: Mac Mini running OSX 10.7.5
Virtual machine: Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon 64-bit
Using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

I am trying to make the linux connect to the internet. For some reason I can access the host computer with 192.168.2.100. Its set up to show me a web-page that says "It works". This I can see from the linux. But I cannot reach anything on the internet. Either FireFox says "Unable to connect" or when I run `nslookup google.com` I get `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.

My setting on VirtualBox under the `Network` tab are:

- `Bridge Adapter`
- `vnic0`
- promiscouos Mode`:`Allow All`.
- If it makes a difference, the host has a WiFi connection to the home router.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to connect to the Internet from within the VM, just use NAT rather than a bridge.

For more VirtualBox networking info, see  www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: Thanks, for those with the same problem: `NAT` works, and also `Bridge` with `WiFi (Airport)`. The second one works probably because the real connection is through a WiFi connection.

Answer (score 0):

Or just open the virtual machine, go to *Devices → Network*, then click *Connect network adapter*.

If it seems already connected, click again to re-enable.